# Having issue creating a new shopify theme. | "Could not create theme with name"

Tags: node.js, shopify, node-modules

```
npm install -g @shopify/cli @shopify/theme
shopify theme init
cd "dresit"
shopify theme dev --store dresit
```

I am getting error couldn't create theme with name "Development"

It's first Shopify trial for me and the stack trace points inside node_modules. It seems to be a setup issue but I am unable to identify.

Any pointers are appreciated

Attaching terminal screenshots

[image]

[image]

I tried re installing shopify cli
recreated a new project
logged out and back into the shopify cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows an error. You need to pass Shopify store URL. Your command should be like

```
shopify theme dev --store my-store
```

**my-store** will be replaced by Shopify store URL which you can find from you Shopify store

[image]